# How do you assign a NumberTab using .Net API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm using the .Net API via DocuSign.eSign.dll and I'm trying to assign a DocuSign.eSign.Model.Number object to the signer, however, I don't see a method to assign it to the DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer.

According to some other resources, using the REST API one can assign a Number Tab using the following syntax:

```
{

   "signers": [
        {
            "tabs": {
                "numberTabs": [
                    {
                        "validationPattern": "",
                        "validationMessage": "",
...
```

However, using the .Net API via the provided DocuSign.eSign.dll - the assignment method of Tabs is via the DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer.Tabs container. This object appears to have the ability to assign tabs, however the NumberTabs definition on this object is as follows:

```
[DataMember(Name = "numberTabs", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public List<double?> NumberTabs { get; set; }
```

In order to assign a list of DocuSign.eSign.Model.Number objects, I would have expected that the above data member should be set-up like the following:

```
[DataMember(Name = " numberTabs ", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public List<Number> NumberTabs { get; set; }
```

Since this isn't the case, can you let me know how I can assign the Number tab using the .Net API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug with the latest DocuSign.eSign Nuget Package version ([2.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.0))

The C# SDK does list the Number tabs as follows. Documentation [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/main/csharp/DocuSign/eSign/Model/Tabs.cs#L189-L190)

```
 [DataMember(Name="numberTabs", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
 public List<Number> NumberTabs { get; set; }
```

You can either switch back to previous version ([2.0.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.0.6)) of the DocuSign.eSign nuget package or directly compile the [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) and use it.

```
Install-Package DocuSign.eSign.dll -Version 2.0.6
```

**Update:**

This issue has been fixed with Nuget package [2.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.2)

Comment: Thanks - using a previous version (2.0.6) worked for me. Do you know when the latest version of the DocuSign.eSign Nuget Package will have this corrected?

Comment: @Claudio There have been several new releases of the DocuSign.eSign nuget packages. As of today we have version [2.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.4)