# Invalid ScaleValue assignment

Tags: c#, docusignapi

In the latest DocuSign SDK, I have noticed that the member "ScaleValue" type has changed from `string` to `Number`. 
My previous code used to be :

```
SignHere signHere = new SignHere
{
    DocumentId = ....,
    ScaleValue = "0.6",
    XPosition = "150",
    YPosition = "150",
};
```

I have adapted it to below :

```
SignHere signHere = new SignHere
{
    DocumentId = ....,
    ScaleValue = new Number { OriginalValue = "0.6" },
    XPosition = "150",
    YPosition = "150",
};
```

However, that seems to be the cause of an issue when submitting my package for creation. Below is the error message I get :

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
  "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Single]' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List&lt;T&gt;) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'recipients.signers[0].tabs.signHereTabs[0].scaleValue.originalValue', line 1, position 28730."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this a bug with the version [2.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.4)  and [2.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.3) of the Docusign.eSign Nuget Package

Good news is that its already been fixed in the SDK [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/commit/c25159e1c7a20fa19e8b9781f20f9eb94621f9c0).

Until the new nuget package is released, you can either fall back to an older version ([2.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.2)) of the Nuget Package or build the [SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) yourself.

```
Install-Package DocuSign.eSign.dll -Version 2.1.2
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006747/1219543) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually, I can confirm that this bug was not existing in 2.1.2 (introduced in 2.1.3).